# Updating Record With Click Button

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

Hi folks I need some help I'm new to programming. I'm trying to input a sign out time from a Timer I have on my application into a column from existing record for time application. I'm trying to use the parameters for my SQL commands and I listed two different ways below. Can anyone get me some pointers.

I'm also getting a syntax error when I click the submit button which seems to be coming from the time.

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label8_Time.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyy hh:mm")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_SignOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3_SignOut.Click
    Dim ask As MsgBoxResult
    ask = MsgBox("Are You Sure You Would Like To Sign Out", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, " Message Details")
    If ask = (MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        connect.Open()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand() With {
                    .Connection = connect
                }
                             '/ Current Parameter Set I tried 
        command.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1_FirstName.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@LAST", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2_LastName.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@EMPID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3_EmployeeID.Text   'Conversion in Question
        command.Parameters.Add("@RECID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox4_RecordID.Text 'Conversion in Question
        command.Parameters.Add("@SIGNTIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now.ToString

                           '/ 1st Parameter Set I tried     
        'command.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", TextBox1_FirstName.Text, DbType.String)
        'command.Parameters.Add("@LAST", TextBox2_LastName.Text, DbType.String)
        'command.Parameters.Add("@EMPID", TextBox3_EmployeeID.Text, DbType.Int32)   'Conversion in Question
        'command.Parameters.Add("@RECID", TextBox4_RecordID.Text, DbType.Int32)   'Conversion in Question
        'command.Parameters.Add("SIGNOUT", Now.ToString, DbType.DateTime)

        'command = New SqlCommand("UPDATE EMPLOYEELOG SET OUTTIME = @SIGNOUT WHERE FIRST= @FIRSTNAME and LAST = @LASTNAME and EMPLOYEEID=@EMPID and IDNO=@RECID", connect)

        command.CommandText = $"Update EmployeeLog  set  OUTTIME = {Now.ToString} WHERE FIRST={TextBox1_FirstName.Text}and LAST={TextBox2_LastName.Text} And EMPID={TextBox3_EmployeeID.Text} and RECID={TextBox4_RecordID}"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: "Some pointers" for what, exactly?  Is your code not working in some way?  You mention a syntax error, but don't provide any information about that error.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The time is 09-29-2017 09:32.... When I Enter the record that needs to be update I'm get this error. **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '9'.' **  The '9' would be referring to the time.

Comment: `Parameters.Add("@SIGNTIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now.ToString`  using `DbType.DateTime` means you are telling it you will be providing a DateTime type, but then you pass a string.  Pass `DateTime.Now` as the value without `.ToString()`

Comment: It says its' not a part of the SqlDbType when I try the DateTime.Now

Comment: @1kok1: What *specifically* did you try and what *specifically* was the error?  We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: I tried to use                                 command.Parameters.Add("@SIGNTIME", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

This should work and will also catch any exceptions.

```vb
Private Sub Button3_SignOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3_SignOut.Click
    Dim ask As MsgBoxResult
    ask = MsgBox("Are You Sure You Would Like To Sign Out", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, " Message Details")
    If ask = (MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        Try
            connect.Open()
            Using command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE EMPLOYEELOG SET OUTTIME = @SIGNOUT WHERE FIRST= @FIRSTNAME and LAST = @LASTNAME and EMPLOYEEID=@EMPID and IDNO=@RECID", connect)
                command.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1_FirstName.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@LAST", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2_LastName.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@EMPID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox3_EmployeeID.Text)
                command.Parameters.Add("@RECID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox4_RecordID.Text)
                command.Parameters.Add("@SIGNOUT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now

                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: `Parameters.Add() is considered deprecated` This is not true.  **One** overload (`String, Object`) is deprecated.  In fact, `Add` is preferred over `AddWithValue` see  [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: MatSnow It's giving me an error with with Using "command" stating Variable "command" hides a variable in an enclosing block

Comment: @1kok1 I guess you get this error because you mixed my example with some parts of your code. Especially `Dim command As ...`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all that in the Where clause to uniquely identify the record to be updated? This is just a guess, but IDNO is the PK of the Employee log so this is all that is necessary in the Where clause. Putting extra stuff asks for trouble. For example, William could sign out as Will, Willy, Bill, Billy or even William. You will never get a match! EMPLOYEEID is a FK from the employees table so first name and last name shouldn't even be in the log table. Ignore if this is not so. I know this is just a comment and soon, maybe, I'll be able to post a comment. :-)